# Best way to work with impala and hive? impyla or pyodbc ?

Tags: python, hive, odbc, pyodbc, impala

I need to work on both hive and impala using python. I found out there are few  options:

```
for hive: 
  a.impyla
  b.pyodbc
  c.hive/lib/py (modules in it) 

For impala:
  a. impyla 
  b. pyodbc
```

So it seems pyodbc and impyla both can be used to connect to hive and impala. Which one is better?

It seems pyodbc module work for both hive and impala but needs to install hive 
and imapla odbc drivers, is that right?

Any similar driver dependency on impyla?